# ManyToOne realtionship in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Well, I have a class `Feeding.java` and a class `User.java`

One Feeding should have one User but a User can have many Feedings.

This is my `Feeding.java` class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tblFeeding")
public class Feeding {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idFeeding;
    private LocalDateTime dateFeeding;
    private double amountFeeding;
    private String foodFeeding;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private User user;
}
```

This is my `User.java` class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "tbl_User")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idUser;
    private String nameUser;
    private String email;
    private String passwordUser;
```

The problem at the moment is that I can save feeding object with an userId that doesn't exist and this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Do the tables already exist or you have created them with Hibernate ORM?

Comment: @Davide I create them with Hibernate ORM

Comment: Is the foreign constraint being created as well (you can enable the logging of the queries)? How are you doing the insert? Does the foreign constraint exist in the database? Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A foreign constraint is missing. If you have created the table with Hibernate ORM it shouldn't happen but if you've created the table in a different way, it's possible that the foreign constraint has not been created.

You would need to run a SQL query similar to this one:

```
ALTER TABLE Feeding
ADD CONSTRAINT id_user_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES User;
```

Note that the query might be different, you need to check the exact query for your database.

This query is from the [Hibernate ORM documentation example for many-to-one associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-one).

Comment: If I do  the ALTER TABLE I can still put in an id which does not exist

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: I am using MySql

Comment: There is probably something wrong in the way you are doing the insert. make sure to commit the transaction and we need to see the code to help you